# using column names as a function argument in user-defined function in R

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

```
id <- 1:30
math<-rnorm(30,1,10)
history<-rnorm(30,1,10)

data<-data.frame(id,math,history)
```

For example I want to make a function that generate one column without using {{}} or tidy evaluation. I want to use standard evaluation

```
cal<-function(data,x,y){

data<-dplyr::mutate(data,
          paste0(x,y,'_sub')= data[[x]]-data[[y]])

return(data)
}



results<-cal(data,'math','history')
```

by doing so, I want this function to make a new column named 'mathhistory_sub'.
but it does not work.

how can I manipulate column name in user-defined function?
(not using {{}}. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could `paste0()` function to concatenate the column names together to create a new column name:

```
cal <- function(data, x, y){
  new_colname <- paste0(x, y, '_sub')
  data[[new_colname]] <- data[[x]] - data[[y]]
  return(data)
}

results<-cal(data,'math','history')

results
   id        math     history mathhistory_sub
1   1   2.0306826  -2.2660206       4.2967032
2   2  11.8307311 -15.4640844      27.2948156
3   3  19.8249942   8.9421041      10.8828901
4   4  -5.0609085   3.5006593      -8.5615678
5   5   3.2410170   8.0059213      -4.7649042
6   6  22.6279894  -6.7597936      29.3877830
7   7  -3.7346896  -7.0488644       3.3141748
8   8  -8.6542502  19.7173492     -28.3715994
9   9  -3.4973431  28.4070630     -31.9044061
10 10 -20.6058136  -1.9461030     -18.6597107
11 11   3.8458925  -5.0921362       8.9380287
12 12  -2.2289963   7.8238182     -10.0528145
13 13  -8.9279480 -15.0273763       6.0994283
14 14  11.7167276   0.7785000      10.9382275
15 15  -8.1183415  13.1005876     -21.2189291
16 16   0.1933635   1.9965524      -1.8031889
17 17   1.3601013 -14.9117793      16.2718806
18 18   4.6899564  -2.6726977       7.3626541
19 19 -21.1364118  18.2677203     -39.4041322
20 20  -3.8133678 -10.5379770       6.7246092
21 21  -2.7514612  -0.5579924      -2.1934688
22 22  -3.2336643  14.0226684     -17.2563328
23 23   7.3933230   7.7911264      -0.3978034
24 24  -4.8189215  -2.7412081      -2.0777133
25 25  13.3792587   3.8729858       9.5062729
26 26 -18.6586839   8.7138439     -27.3725278
27 27  -8.0155164   4.4805694     -12.4960858
28 28   3.6682551 -11.5531626      15.2214177
29 29   6.3487094  19.8509390     -13.5022296
30 30   8.1119180 -17.2755867      25.3875047
```